# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}\log (\Gamma(s,x)) \,ds \,dx $

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

The following result for the logarithm integral of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is well known

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\log(\Gamma(x)) \,dx  = \dfrac{1}{2}\log 2 \pi  \tag {1}$$

I want to evaluate a two-variable similar integral but with the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $\Gamma(s,x)$ given by

> $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\log(\Gamma(s,x)) \,ds\,dx   \tag {2}$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cln+(%5CGamma(x,y))+%5C,dx+%5C,dy) gives $I \approx -0.515942$ but I have no idea how to prove this result.

**Is there some "pretty" result for $(2)$ like that one of the integral $(1)$?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: (1) can be proved using the reflection formula but we don't have an equivalent form for the incomplete gamma function